# How to make user input 0 produce output "1234"

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

This is my code below. When I type in 0, it just outputs 0. I want it so that when you input 0, it outputs "1234". Can someone help? Thanks. I am unsure what I have done wrong here - but from the IF statement, I have it so that when the input is equal to 0, it should output "1234".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Program{
    public static void main ( String[] args ){

       double number;
       Scanner user = new Scanner( System.in );
       System.out.print("Enter number: ");
       number = user.nextInt();
       double answer;    

       if (number % 2 == 0) {       
          answer = number * number;     
          System.out.println(answer);     
       } 
       else if (number == 0) {
          System.out.println("1234");
       }            
       else {        
          answer = number / 2;     
          System.out.println(answer);
       }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s 0 % 2? Stepping through the code or some simple logging would help you understand what’s happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because 0 % 2 == 0 then the first if block is executing, try checking if number is equal to 0 first, then check elseif(number % 2 == 0)